# Email attachments not working in PHP

Tags: php, email, attachment

I was trying to add a feature on my website which allows users to add attachments while sending emails. I tried this with PHP, but the code is not working. It is neither uploading the attachment, nor inserting the URL of the attachment in my database, nor echoing the confirmation message.

All the other form code is processed successfully, except the attachment. Please suggest me what changes should be made to the code:

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['attachment']))
{
    if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 52428800)
    {
        $attachment_results =  "Sorry, your attachment could not be processed as it is exceeding the limit of 50 MB.";
    }
    else
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
           $attachment_results =  "Sorry, your attachment could not be processed due to some error. Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            $attachment_results = "Your attachment was also processed successfully.<br>
            File name: " . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "<br>Attachment Size: " . $_FILES['file']['size'];
            $destination = "attachments/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['name'], $destination);
            $url = "https://$domain_name/$destination";
        }
    }
    echo $attachment_results;
}
```

Later in the script, `$url` is to be inserted in the MySQL database, but that doesn't work either. Just a blank variable is inserted in the database.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<input type="file" name="attachment" style="color: #000000;"><label>(Maximum 50 MB)    </label>
<!-- Other Form Code -->
</form>
```

Comment: have u give 0777 permission to directory

Comment: I haven't.. how can I do it?? Does it require some other PHP code??

Comment: you can do it via ftp client... and, i would definitely use some php library (e.g. phpmailer) for sending emails with atachments -> it is pain without it...

Comment: are u using linux or windows

Comment: I m using windows 8 64 bit..

Comment: I thought replace $_FILES['file']['XXX'] with $_FILES['attachemnt']['XXX'] will work

Comment: #nevermind I am already using phpmailer, but according to the concept of my site, I want manual attachments.. not the ones added through phpmailer..

Comment: @TanmayVij is ur file uploading now to folder??

Comment: No @Saurav, it's still not working..

Comment: pasted complete working answer chk and vote up

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

print_r($_FILES);
    if ($_FILES['attachment']['size'] > 52428800)
    {
        $attachment_results =  "Sorry, your attachment could not be processed as it is exceeding the limit of 50 MB.";
    }
    else
    {
        if ($_FILES["attachment"]["error"] > 0)
        {
           $attachment_results =  "Sorry, your attachment could not be processed due to some error. Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            $attachment_results = "Your attachment was also processed successfully.<br>
            File name: " . $_FILES['attachment']['name'] . "<br>Attachment Size: " . $_FILES['file']['size'];
            $destination = "attachments/" . $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $destination);
            $url = "https://$domain_name/$destination";
        }
    }
    echo $attachment_results;
}
?>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<input type="file" name="attachment" style="color: #000000;"><label>(Maximum 50 MB)    </label>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: working dude simple paste code and check if file gets uploded in folder

Comment: Also, I m getting this error: Array ( [attachment] => Array ( [name] => Untitled.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpF9EB.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 108912 ) )

Comment: Now all the code is working perfectly fine. Thanks. That error also disappeared after removing print_r($_FILES);. May I ask you why was that line needed??

Comment: kk thanks a lot.. sorry, but I won't be able to vote up your answer due to lack of reputation as I joined Stackoverflow today only..

Comment: tick it as answer, you can do so